# How to suppress the warnings of unused context bounds raised via -Wunused:params?

Tags: scala

In Scala `2.13.5` the linting of unused context bounds is added via `-Wunused:params` . This is raising the following error:

```
[error] /home/knoldus/myproject/src/main/scala/edu/knoldus/Base.scala:16:29: parameter value evidence$1 in class Base is never used
[error] abstract class Base[+A: MyClassTag] {
```

This error can be suppressed by removing `-Wunused:params` check. Is there another way around? Don't really want to remove the check `-Wunused:params`.

Comment: Why not removing the context bound if it is not being used?

Comment: Can't do that as it is legacy code.

Comment: you can do anything in any code if it is not breaking externally facing APIs

Comment: Check out this [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html) how to suppress warnings